# Intent for switching between Activities kills my second Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

here is my problem:
I have multiple activities in my application, two of them are a bit "special".
Activity A is a home type of activity, used to launch the other activities. It also holds some other info, that can be updated from the background (uses onNewIntent). In the manifest I've declared it as singleTop. It starts other activities for result, so it can't be singleTask or Instance (startActivityForResult doesn't work with them).
Activity B is a standalone Activity, that is launched on certain events, also declared as singleTop. It also starts other activities for result and also uses its onNewIntent.
I've two separate notifications, that are linked to the corresponding Activity.
I'm using for both

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

The normal flow is:

1. A is running
2. Something happens - B is launched
3. if user presses Home button I have two notifications for A and B

And the problem:
if user presses notification for A, A is launched, but B is killed (due to clear_top flag)
if after that user presses notification for B new B is launched (activity is dead, **but I need the old instance**)

I've read this article - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html
To my understanding FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK should launch the activities in separate tasks and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP should not kill B in this case.

A workaround is to rework the logic, make them singleTasks and handle the result from other activities in onNewIntent, but I prefer not to go this way if another solution is possible.
I've also tried

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
```

and

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

to launch B, but neither works.

Comment: Your implementation is wrong, you must not keep instance of an activity if its removed from the back stack. You must be able to save your activity state and recreate its state on every launch.

Comment: I agree with you, but in this case it's not an option. For me this is inherited code and the activity itself holds a lot of information and states (I know it's not correct, I've tried to refactor it and move most of the business logic in some managers, but a lot is still there) In this case I need something like a singleton Activity, but without using singleInstance.

Comment: If your "information" data is a business logic, just move it to a singleton class. You are hacking MVC pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was, that both activities ran on the same task. Despite the documentation FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK doesn't start the Activity in a new task - it puts . You have to use the android:taskAffinity in the manifest for that specific Activity and set it to a unique value. Only then it will be started in a new task. That way FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP used for A, doesn't destroy B.